# how can I make a plot with standard deviation

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like below

```
df<- structure(list(data1 = c(20171205L, 20171205L, 20171205L, 20171205L, 
20171205L, 20171205L, 20171205L, 20171205L, 20171205L, 20171205L, 
20171205L, 20171205L, 20171205L, 20171205L, 20171205L, 20171205L, 
20171205L, 20171205L, 20171205L, 20171205L), data2 = c(0.00546273, 
0.00552377, 0.00549325, 0.00550851, 0.00556954, 0.00560006, 0.00555428, 
0.00560006, 0.0055848, 0.00561532, 0.00555428, 0.0055848, 0.00552377, 
0.00549325, 0.00550851, 0.00556954, 0.00560006, 0.00555428, 0.00560006, 
0.0055848), data3 = c(0.00546273, 0.00552377, 0.00549325, 0.00550851, 
0.00556954, 0.00560006, 0.00555428, 0.00560006, 0.0055848, 0.00561532, 
0.00555428, 0.0055848, 0.00552377, 0.00549325, 0.00550851, 0.00556954, 
0.00560006, 0.00555428, 0.00560006, 0.0055848), mydf = structure(1:20, .Label = c("B02", 
"B03", "B04", "B05", "B06", "C02", "C03", "C04", "C05", "C06", 
"D02", "D03", "D04", "D05", "D06", "E02", "E03", "E04", "E05", 
"E06"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("data1", "data2", "data3", 
"mydf"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

I am trying to get the average and standard deviation of certain rows 
here is what I do

```
# here is to get the mean 

    library(dplyr)
    df2 <- df %>%
      group_by(Group = case_when(
        grepl("02$|03$", mydf)       ~ 1L,
        grepl("04$|05$|06$", mydf)   ~ 2L,
        TRUE                       ~ NA_integer_
      )) %>%
      summarise_at(vars(-mydf), funs(mean(.)))

# here is to get the standard deviation 
df3 <- df %>%
  group_by(Group = case_when(
    grepl("02$|03$", mydf)       ~ 1L,
    grepl("04$|05$|06$", mydf)   ~ 2L,
    TRUE                       ~ NA_integer_
  )) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(-mydf), funs(sd(.)))
```

Then I want to put the mean and their sd but I don't know how to merge these two df together and plot them

the first column is the x- axis (in this case it is 1 and 2)

so data will look like this for the plot (for example):

On 1 for `data1`, it will be `20171205` with a SD of `0`,

On 2 for `data1` , it will be `20171205` with a SD of `0`,

On 1 for `data2`, it will be `0.005556190` with a SD of `4.573063e-05`,

On 2 for `data2`, it will be `0.005553013` with a SD of `4.529097e-05`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be cleaner to do your data manipulations in long format, rather than wide:

```
dff <- df %>%
  # define Group based on mydf, then remove mydf
  mutate(Group = case_when(grepl("02$|03$", mydf) ~ 1L,
                           grepl("04$|05$|06$", mydf) ~ 2L,
                           TRUE ~ NA_integer_)) %>%
  select(-mydf) %>%

  # convert to long format using gather from tidyr package
  tidyr::gather(data, value, -Group) %>%

  # calculate mean & sd within the same summarise() call
  group_by(Group, data) %>%
  summarise(data.mean = mean(value),
            data.sd = sd(value))

> dff
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups: Group [2]
  Group data       data.mean   data.sd
  <int> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1 data1 20171205       0        
2     1 data2        0.00556 0.0000457
3     1 data3        0.00556 0.0000457
4     2 data1 20171205       0        
5     2 data2        0.00555 0.0000453
6     2 data3        0.00555 0.0000453
```

Given the huge difference in values between data1 & data2/data3, there is really no way to plot everything in the same chart & still see the tiny standard deviations associated with the latter. But in principle, you can do something like this (using point to represent mean for each data, & a line range or error bar for k standard deviations away from each mean):

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dff %>% filter(data != "data1"),
       aes(x = data, y = data.mean,color = data,
           ymin = data.mean - data.sd, 
           ymax = data.mean + data.sd)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_linerange() +
  facet_grid(~Group)
```

[image: plot]